# Dynamically export SQL table to CSV file everysec using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, export-to-csv

I am new to SQL and SSIS work. I'd like to dynamically export SQL datatable to a CSV file everysec using SSIS. one of column name RECIPE STATUS, value is 1 OR 2 (int) (1 is new Recipe, 2 is old recipe which is existed), Another column name is RECIPE NAME, value is AAABBB (varchar) some more columns with values In Database table, only one row data avaialble, it will be changed ev sec. So we are trying to export it to csv file to log different/unique RECIPENAMES and data for analysis.

Table Schema is

```
 SELECT TOP 5 [RowID]
 ,[RowInsertTime]
 ,[TransId]
 ,[RecipeStatus]
 ,[RecipeName]
 ,[RecipeTagName]
 ,[Value]
 ,[ReadStatus]
 ,[sData1]
 ,[sData2]
 ,[sData3]
 ,[nData1]
 ,[nData2]
 ,[nData3]
 FROM [MES].[dbo].[MESWrite_RecipeData]
```

While exporting, based on RECIPE STATUS value if 1, then Insert/create a new row in CSV and export. (Its a simple insert TSQL statement, insert into csvfile (values from databsetable)

if value 2 means RECIPENAME value is AAABBB existed in CSV already. so find and update other columns values. so in this case don't create a new row in csv. (i can say update all othercolumns with values from database table to csv where RECIPENAME="AAABBB") like Update Query in T-SQL

. finally if we have to send this SSIS package to a customer, it can be executable file. or how to make secured? Please help me ..

Comment: show table data, it's unclear where recipe existed if value 2: in same records with value 2 or in the new records with value 1

Comment: It doesn't look too effective you want to export all data from a relational database to csv -and work with that file I assume-, especially not every sec. Are you sure this is the right and only way to do this? E.g. Why not using another table which keeps tracking of changes on the way you like? I think you could get better answers by telling the community what's your goal for the end of the day.

Comment: How to insert / show the Table Data

Comment: In order to have a SSIS package run for a customer.... that customer needs SSIS installed and licenced in their computer. Basically SSIS is not for deploying to customers. If you want something that can be deployed as an executable, just build something in .Net and compile it. You should not use SSIS for this purpose.

Comment: Hi ElecticLIama, Customer has licensed SQLSever, which can have SSIS. if we do in .Net and executable file, whether customer require Visual Studio for running executable file? Customer doesn't have VisualStudio.

Comment: Hi Mark, 
The given task is to export table data to CSV file without duplicates. Why they are using CSV file I don't know really.

As you understood rightly, I have a database table with one row that is updated very often and I want to store every changed row into a csv file without duplicates.

Is this possible to do using SSIS or some means